# Pass function with or without argument as argument in C++

Tags: c++

I would like to pass either a void function without an argument or a void function with an argument to a constructor as an argument. Like this:

```
DailyActivity activity1(&function1)
```

or

```
DailyActivity activity2(&function2(uint_t 1))
```

The function passed should be triggered when `DailyActivity::run()` is called.

The header of `DailyActivity` looks like this:

```
class DailyActivity {
  typedef void (*function_type)();

  public:
    DailyActivity(void (*f)());
    virtual void run();

  private:
    function_type m_function;
};
```

The constructor and run() function looks like this:

```
DailyActivity::DailyActivity(void (*f)()) : m_function((*f)) {
}

DailyActivity::run() {
  m_function();
}
```

But I do not manage to (1) define the typedef in a correct way enabling the two different functions to be accepted and (2) pass the argument o function2 successfully.

Comment: You are talking about two completely different function types. A single `typedef` will not be able to accommodate them both.  You will have to use either use variadic parameters or templates to accomplish what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `std::function` with `lambda` or `std::bind`:

```
class DailyActivity {
  public:
    explicit DailyActivity(std::function<void ()> f) : m_function(f) {}
    void run() { m_function(); }

  private:
    std::function<void ()> m_function;
};
```

And call it

```
DailyActivity activity1(&function1);
DailyActivity activity2([](){function2(1);});
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/RlnnFg)

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately, I am using an environment that do not support the std:function as I have understood it :(

Comment: If you can't use C++11, maybe you can use [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/function.html) then ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Unfortunately C++ can't process partial functions, so you have to overload your constructor to take both function and an argument as two separate arguments and the second one to take care of a parameterless one. Then you're going to have two function pointers and one of them should be null.

Another option is to wrap the functions into a lambda.